# Defining Rules for implicit C++ constexpr Style Compile Time Evaluation

Tags: language-design

After reading and watching a talk about `constexpr` in C++ I thought:

> That's so cool!

Being a language nerd, I thought about defining a new programming language with the `constexpr` idea baked in implicitly. Meaning no `constexpr` keyword. As far as I understand the general rules for evaluating `constexpr` at compile time are:

1. The function or variable must be declared with the `constexpr` keyword.
2. If it is a function its parameters must all be known at compile time. If it is a variable it must be initialized when declared with a value known at compile time.
3. The value of a `constexpr` function/variable is needed at compile time or else the compiler is allowed to defer it to run time.

But lets say that we remove condition 1 and 3. Then the compiler would evaluate anything that it could at compile time. But you might get the wrong result in some cases. Here is an example:

```
var file = new File("Data.txt");
...
...
```

In this case the path is known at compile time therefore the file is searched for on the machine the program is compiled on and not the user's machine. In some cases that might be what the programmer needs but it often isn't.

So the question is: Could a set of additional rules be defined so that the compiler can make the distinction?

Comment: You could certainly have a keyword that does the opposite of what the `constexpr` keyword does.

Comment: @Ryan1729 I too thought about that. Something like this
`runtime var file = new File("Data.txt"); `.